# zoom in and zoom out on click image view

Tags: android

I make a android application in which i want to apply zoom in and zoom out on every image.my code is show image in full screen and having two button next and back i want when i click image zoom in and zoom out effect.
i want change image when i clicked next and back and also want zoom effect on every image.how can i do this.please help me sir.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button btn1, btn2;
ImageView ib;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ib = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
}
public OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() 
{
        int counter = 0;
        // The images are located in res/drawable-xxhdpi
    final Integer pics[] = 
        {
            R.drawable.a, 
            R.drawable.b,
            R.drawable.c,
            R.drawable.d,
            R.drawable.e,
            R.drawable.f,
            R.drawable.g,
            R.drawable.h,
            R.drawable.i,
            R.drawable.j,
            R.drawable.k, 
            R.drawable.l,
            R.drawable.m,
            R.drawable.n,
            R.drawable.o,
            R.drawable.p,
            R.drawable.q,
            R.drawable.r,
            R.drawable.s, 
            R.drawable.t,
            R.drawable.u,
            R.drawable.v,
            R.drawable.w,
            R.drawable.x,

        }; 

     @Override
     public void onClick(final View v)
     {
         switch(v.getId())
         {
             case R.id.button1:
                 if(counter < 25)
         {
            counter++;
            ib.setImageResource(pics[counter]);

         }
             break;
             case R.id.button2:
                 if(counter > 0)
                 {
                     counter--;
                     ib.setImageResource(pics[counter]);

                 }
             break;
         }
   }
};
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


} 


 <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity" >
  <TableRow
     android:id="@+id/tb1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClick" />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/back"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>
     </TableRow>
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/alhambra" />
     </TableLayout>
```

Comment: There is no question in your text.

Comment: how i implement zoom in and zoom out on every image which are come from an integer array

Comment: i want change image when i clicked next and back and also want zoom effect on every image.how can i do this.please help me sir.

Comment: whether is easier when you click on a small image show fragment or dialog with a large image?